# How to divide total score by amount of input items

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a dynamic calculator with several amount of input items (user decides)

Let say, I want to sum all the input numbers up and then divide by amount of all inputs that took part in calculating.

How can I do it?

I tried to find sth on YouTube and another posts but unfortunately didnt found. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce can do this cleanly.

```js
const getSumOfArray = (array) => array.reduce((sum, curr) => sum += curr, 0)

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const sum = getSumOfArray(numbers)/numbers.length
```

Comment: +1 for the nice use of `.reduce`, but I think it might be a bit better to use `sum + curr` rather than `sum += curr`. The value returned from the arrow function will become the new `sum` in the next call, so there's no need to hackily use `+=`. `+=` might imply that `sum` is scoped outside of the arrow function (which it is not).

Answer (score 2):

Try to save all numbers in an array then add them up and divide by the length of array

```js
let array = [NUMBERS]
let final = 0
array.forEach(e => {
  final += e
});
final /= array.length
```

Comment: That's really possible it will work bro. I am going to test that tomorrow and make an update. Thanks for now :)))

Comment: @Aseyounar This won't work. `.lenght` is not a real property. Also, you're better off using `.reduce()` to get the sum rather than using an intermediate variable (see my answer for a full example).

Comment: @MichaelM. .lenght is a real property! https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_length_array try out this example.

Comment: @Waradu That is the `.length` property I've edited your answer to fix your typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping a running sum that gets added to and a running total that gets incremented each time. Then, all you need to do is calculate `sum/total`, rather than the overhead of getting the sum of an array of values each time:

```js
let sum = 0;
let total = 0;

const numEl = document.getElementById('num');
document.getElementById('record').addEventListener('click', () => {
  sum += parseFloat(numEl.value);
  total++;
});

const output = document.getElementById('output');
document.getElementById('avg').addEventListener('click', () => {
  output.textContent = sum/total
});
```

```html
Input a value: <input type="number" id="num" /><button id="record">Record</button>
<br>
<button id="avg">Calculate average</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

If you already have an array of values, then use `.reduce()` to get its sum, then divide by `.length`:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // example data

const average = arr.reduce((a, x) => a + x)/arr.length;
console.log(average);
```

Comment: @Aseyounar If my answer solved your issue and best helped you, then you can mark it as correct to help guide others with the same issue in the future.